# how can set customize color to pie chart using D3.js?

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, charts

I am new to angularjs ,i made a pie chart,how do i customize the colour for every component in pie chart i use this but one problem with this

```
  color = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(['Successful', 'Unsuccessful','Best One', 'Moderate'])
             .range(['#1ea6e0', '#fbb111','#eb4626', '#c568e4']);
```

method when in pie chart when only on item then first color is applied even the item is last one.
how can i make this that if there is one component and its defined in .domain at last then the colour for fill should be applied the last one in rang i.e colour should match the order as component and colour position are in domain and rang array.
anyone can guide me?

Comment: Can you provide some code?. Where you assign colors to data would be useful

Comment: @Klaujesi yes look at this https://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1058/

Comment: your domain is: ['Successful', 'Unsuccessful','Best One', 'Moderate'] and your data is: 194, 567, 1314, ..., 1383. They doesn't match. Depending on values they assume position

Comment: @Klaujesi i also want to fill colour according to position

Comment: @Klaujesi if a component has 4th position then it should be fill with colour on 4th position

Comment: It's not about position, it's about 'mapping' values with categories

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88501/discussion-between-klaujesi-and-hassan).

Answer (score 0):

Try this and you'll see it:

```
buildChart('#chart', [
    {"label":"One", "value":1}, 
    {"label":"Two", "value":2}, 
    {"label":"Three", "value":3},
    {"label":"Four", "value":4},
    {"label":"Five", "value":1},
    {"label":"Six", "value":2},
    {"label":"Seven", "value":3},
    {"label":"Eight", "value":4},
    {"label":"Nine", "value":1},
    {"label":"Ten", "value":2}
]);
```

every `"value"` must fall on 4 categories `['Successful', 'Unsuccessful','Best One', 'Moderate']` then they are grouped by Categories

> The pie layout converts data into arcs (slices of the pie), and the
>   sort comparator specifies how the arcs should be sorted in terms of
>   their angles.  By default, the arcs are sorted by value in descending
>   order, so the largest value will have the overall starting angle (zero
>   by default).  So essentially, the sort determines in what order the
>   angles are set, starting from the starting angle.

To disable this use: .sort(null)

change your code to this:

```
var pie = d3.layout.pie()
.value(function(d) { return d.value; })
 .sort(null);
```

here is the working code: https://jsfiddle.net/bqp6hdfr/

Comment: i got no pie chart in this fiddle that you just pasted above

Comment: due you include external references, must enable blocked content even insecure

Comment: Add this to your html, before divs: <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" ></script> and remove external references from the left panel pressing "x" next to "d3.v3.min.js"

Comment: after doing that still no pie chart is displayed

Comment: your explorer it's blocking all External Resources, you must allow access to blocked content or try another explorer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88504/discussion-between-klaujesi-and-hassan).